# html2canvas not working in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, d3.js, html2canvas

[Export image is looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKzrz.png)I am taking export of my charts. So I convert my image from in base64 string using html2Canvas. It is working fine in chrome & IE but not working in firefox. Please help

```
html2canvas($("#" + chart + actualViewCode), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                $("#" + chart + actualViewCode + "-image").val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
                createSunburstChartExportFormatTableContent(chart + actualViewCode);
                callbackFunction(chartId);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this haven't tested yet .

> Keep an hidden `anchor` element in the `DOM` and update the `href` property
>   of the element inside onrendered handler.

```
    $('#div').click(function() {
      html2canvas($("#" + chart + actualViewCode), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
          var a = $("#" + chart + actualViewCode + "-image");
          a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
          createSunburstChartExportFormatTableContent(chart + actualViewCode);
          callbackFunction(chartId);
          a.download = 'somefilename.png';
          a.click();
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it is not working for us. Our export image is looking like https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKzrz.png